# Seeking Function to calculate red-edgeNDVI in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, function, vegetation-index

I am trying to calculate the red-edgeNDVI ((NIR – red edge)/(NIR + red edge)) of an Image.Collection in Google Earth Engine. There is a built in function for NDVI but not for red-edge NDVI. The code I have is below but I get the error message "image.NIR is undefined". I'm sure this is a simple syntax issue related to the function but I've tried everything I could think of and I just can't get it to work.

Can you tell me what I'm missing?

```js
/**
 * Function to mask clouds using the Sentinel-2 QA band
 * @param {ee.Image} image Sentinel-2 image
 * @return {ee.Image} cloud masked Sentinel-2 image
 */
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask)
  .divide(10000);
}

  // Load Sentinel-2 TOA reflectance data.
  var S2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
                  .filterDate('2017-06-01', '2017-09-30')
                  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
                  //Select required bands only
                  .select('B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'B8A', 'QA60')
                  //Apply cloud mask
                  .map(maskS2clouds);

//Create band variables
var redEdge = S2.select('B5');
var NIR = S2.select('B8');

//Function to calculate redEdgeNDVI
var add_reNDVI = function(image){
  var redEdgeNDVI = image.NIR.subtract(redEdge).divide(NIR.add(redEdge)).rename('reNDVI');
    return image.addBands(reNDVI);
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code, `S2` is an `ImageCollection`, so when you "create band variables" you're just getting ImageCollections in which every image inside has only the selected band, which is useful. As you well commented, `add_reNDVI` is a function that will take every image in the collection and calculate reNDVI. So you have to `map` that function over the collection to get what you want.

```js
// Load Sentinel-2 TOA reflectance data.
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
                .filterDate('2017-06-01', '2017-09-30')
                // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
                //Select required bands only
                .select('B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'B8A', 'QA60')
                //Apply cloud mask
                .map(maskS2clouds);

//Function to calculate redEdgeNDVI
var add_reNDVI = function(image){
  //Create band variables
  var redEdge = image.select('B5');
  var NIR = image.select('B8');
  var redEdgeNDVI = NIR.subtract(redEdge).divide(NIR.add(redEdge)).rename('reNDVI');
    return image.addBands(redEdgeNDVI);
};
var s2_reNDVI = S2.map(add_reNDVI)
Map.centerObject(s2_reNDVI.first())
Map.addLayer(s2_reNDVI.first())
```

I guess you'll need to filter by bounds at some point, that is why I just took the first image out of the collection to check if it's working

Comment: Thanks @Rodrigo. This worked fine. I've posted a follow-up question (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/320967/calculating-cirededge-from-a-sentinel-2-composite-image-and-adding-as-a-band-in). I supect you may be able to answer this one too.